# Reset a user account inside a MySQL database using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a website that uses MySQL as the database. The website is coded with PHP, its not WordPress or any other out of the box solution. I am trying to log into my user account but I am getting an incorrect login for some reason. How can I reset the password using phpmyadmin?

I have gone in and edited my account and changed the password. That did not work.

I have changed the password and changed the drop down for that row to MD5. That did not work.

I have changed the password and change the drop down for that row to password. Also, did not work.

Am I doing something wrong? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you must check if you add those data to the right table you created in right database, If you can post some images it will be easier to help you. (Sorry, can't comment. Not enought reputation.)

Comment: There's no way to know how to do this without knowing how passwords are stored in the MySQL table. Usually passwords are stored in hashed form (so a badguy who breaks in and steals the table's contents will have a slightly hard time guessing them). See this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php